# Windows 7 Temporary Profile

Tags: windows-7, profile

I would like to force Windows 7 to always load the temporary profile when a user logs off and back on.  Is there a reliable way to force this to happen each time?

Background:  if you are familiar with Windows Steady State for Windows XP, I am trying to replicate the "lock the desktop" feature, which clears the the desktop, my docs, etc, and most user history at a logoff.  Then, when a new user logs on, that user is presented with a like-new computer.  This is different than what Windows Disk Protection (and 3rd party products such as DeepFreeze) does, as it does not require a restart, only a logoff/logon, and only erases certain changes that a user has made (a restart would be performed at night, wiping the machine and restoring it to a like-new state).

Again, the idea is to let each user work in a new, unpolluted space, and then have that space cleaned at each logoff/logon to preserve privacy and to give the next user the same clean desktop, etc to work with.  Windows Steady State is not available for Windows 7 and I have yet to find an acceptable alternative\solution for "locking the desktop."  This temporary profile seems like it could be the answer, but I have only seen it referenced in posts where it was an unwanted annoyance.

Thanks in advance, and if I need to be more clear, I will be.

Answer (score 1):

The temporary user profile is loaded whenever the user's own profile cannot be loaded - i.e. due to permission problems or disk space issues.

However, there is no need to abuse the temporary user profile to get a locked-down user configuration. Making a user's profile [mandatory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241183?v=ws.10%29.asp) would prevent any changes to be saved as well, but still allow the administrator for profile customization.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  Correct me if I am wrong please, but isnt active directory required in order to use mandatory profiles?  These machines would NOT be on a domain, so I dont think that will work.

Comment: To be frank I never tried mandatory user profiles without a domain logon, but [this blog article](http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/windowsxp/articles/457/1/Create-an-XP-Pro-Mandatory-User-Profile-on-the-Local-Machine) suggests that it would be working.